# Rails 3.2.3 End user error messages instead of developer error messages in development mode with consider_all_requests_local = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running my rails 3.2.3 app in development mode.
Even though I have specified

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

in my `config/environments/development.rb` configuration file, I get the "end user friendly" error pages with the red "We're sorry, but something went wrong." when I have errors in my views, instead of the more useful "developer friendly" error pages with stack trace, etc.

What can I do to get the developer friendly error messages?

Among my gems are omniauth and slim

**Edit:**
The problem occurs when there are errors in views. When there are errors in controllers, the developer-friendly errors show correctly.

Comment: are you accessing the site by http://127.0.0.1:<portnumber> or via another IP address?

Comment: @JohnBeynon yes, 0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: try accessing as 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: Apparently this is not possible, as I'm using omniauth-facebook, and facebook doesn't accept "127.0.0.1" as App domain ("localhost") works fine, but suffers from the original problem.

Comment: weird - the consider_all_requests_local is used in conjunction with a function 'local?' in ActionDispatch::Request which checks to see if you are accessing via a local IP which `localhost` will be.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the problem only occurs whenever there are errors in the views. Controller errors work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have had exactly the same problem, described in the question in the bottom. Only saw this message in views, although development mode is and consider_all_requests_local is on. In addition, my file did not contain any illegal utf-8 characters (or was marked via encoding: utf-8).

But today, I finally found the solution for my problem - hope it helps you:

[Rails doesnt log tempalte errors in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624208/rails-doesnt-log-tempalte-errors-in-development-mode/17978388#17978388)