# Rails doesn't log template errors in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, erb

My Rails 3.2.9-app does not show any specific error information to me on errors **in templates**! It doesn't matter if I use haml or erb, I am always getting

> "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

In fact, Webrick **is** in **development** mode and if there are errors in my models or controllers, I get the full ordinary error screen.

### Examples

Example error in my helper-template ("@resource" does not exist, must be "resource"):
-> All I get is this lousy "We are sorry, but something went wrong"
`<% @resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>`

Example error in one of my controllers:
`resposnd_to do |format|`
-> undefined method `resposnd_to' for ...

Comment: Off topic - you need to upgrade to a secure version of rails see http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/11/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-12-3-1-11-and-2-3-17-have-been-released/ and http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this problem!! All in all, I searched for more than 1 year, but now, i finally got the solution:

The problem is to use umlauts or blank spaces in the path of the rails project. If you **move your rails project to a path without umlauts or blanks**, the error message should be shown properly :-)!

Tested on ubuntu-machine, maybe this is important for this bug. This bug appears in rails 3.2.9, 3.2.13 and 3.2.14 definitely.

(consider_all_requests_local is activated of course, this never was the reason)